# Custom icon fonts with Icomoon (group multiple path in 1 class)

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, font-face

i am trying to use customs icon with Icomoon on my project. 
i really love it.
All good until when i try to insert it in HTML on 2 colours icon.

```
<span class="icon-fun-diving">
  <span class="path1"></span>
  <span class="path2"></span>
  <span class="path3"></span>
  <span class="path4"></span>
  <span class="path5"></span>
  <span class="path6"></span>
  <span class="path7"></span>
  <span class="path8"></span>
  <span class="path9"></span>
</span>
```

we can see from above code, there are a bundle of "span" use in order to display it. i know it happens because it's multi colours.

**the question is**

is there any way that i can store these code in one file, then just use single class name to call it in html? as it is easier and tidier to read/control.

example (into something like this):

```
<span class="icon-fun-diving"></span>
```